# Regex match for first ending

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this sample. i want to match first "something" in my text. the "something" have any character in it, so i should use (.*) for it.

Sample:
`start: something, end ... blah blah ... start: something, end`

I tried to match it like this:
`start: (.*) end`

but as you can expect this see last end in my text.

https://www.debuggex.com/r/qfeBXsBybijWDWbp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `?` to your current regex:

```
start: (.*?) end
```

https://www.debuggex.com/r/1VmZTRx0EqgNyH4Y

This will tell the `.*` to match lazily until the word "end".

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy match: `start: (.*?) end`.

Keep in mind it won't match well if `something` has `end` inside it.